# Bash copy file in user homedir MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, copy, home-directory

I'm fairly new (totally new) in Shell writting. I'm using it from time to time to do specific task when my PKG tools are not enough.

I have a folder called licences located in /Library/Application\ Support/ and I want to get it copied in the Library of the user. Luckily every user is named on a specific numeric pattern, my homedir is t25542

So here is my small script :

```
#get the homedir name
USER=`stat -f  '%Su' /Users/t*/

#copy files
ditto /Library/Application\ Support/licences/ /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/licences/
```

It works, *but* I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it since it looks pretty *sloppy*.

Comment: Just being curious: What is *ditto*? Plus, your shell script is syntactically incorrect (bissing closing backquote), and the stat command doesn't make any sense in this context.  You are asking for a more elegant way, but IMHO, the script which you posted here, can't work (because the output of your `stat -f` command produces, at least for me, the error message *cannot read file system information for '%Su': No such file or directory*  - at least in my version of *stat*). Could it be that you are on MacOS? If so, you should say it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. its on Mac, added the tag. Ditto is a binarie in the Mac World.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call it N times to do each of N users yourself? Or do you mean each user should run it to sort himself/herself out?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a little trouble expressing myself in English... In fact the script will be executed remotely via Remote Desktop on all available workstations. On the workstations there can be several t* users (each t* being unique in the park). The "license" folder is on the workstations in /Library/Application Support/ but the script must copy it to each ~/Library/Application Support/ of each user.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of how you might do it:

```
sudo bash -c 'for u in /Users/*/ ; do SRC="/Library/Application Support/licence"; DST="$u/Library/Application Support"; echo cp "$SRC" "$DST"; echo chmod something "$DST/licence" ; done'
```

**Sample Output**

```
cp /Library/Application Support/licence /Users/Shared//Library/Application Support
chmod something /Users/Shared//Library/Application Support/licence
cp /Library/Application Support/licence /Users/fred//Library/Application Support
chmod something /Users/fred//Library/Application Support/licence
cp /Library/Application Support/licence /Users/mark//Library/Application Support
chmod something /Users/mark//Library/Application Support/licence
```

Make a backup first!

At the moment, it only echoes what it would do without actually doing anything, so check carefully that the output looks correct before removing the `echo` in front of `cp`.

Comment: Looks like a real savior to me, am gonna try that ! Cant give you some point since i'm a newbie here but you are in my heart !